# How to POST two files

Tags: json, parsing, post

I am trying to post two different files using the command

```
curl -vX POST http://localhost/api/postJSON -d @input.json -d @input2.json --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I know something is wrong. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Consulting the curl manpage and identify the `-F` option (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F).

There's also an example of uploading multiple files via curl at https://medium.com/@petehouston/upload-files-with-curl-93064dcccc76#e822

```
$ curl -F 'fileX=@/path/to/fileX' -F 'fileY=@/path/to/fileY' ... http://localhost/api/postJSON upload
```